# SWI-Prolog Guitracer X-server

Tags: prolog, cygwin, swi-prolog, xserver

The following error pops up when I try to use the guitracer to trace my SWI-Prolog code using a cygwin terminal:

```
[PCE fatal: @display/display: Failed to connect to X-server at `': no DISPLAY environment variable
*********************************************************************
* You MUST be running the X11 Windowing environment.  If you are,   *
* check the setting of your DISPLAY environment variable as well    *
* the access rights to your X11 server.  See xauth(1) and xhost(1). *
*********************************************************************
        in:     <No exception goal> 
]
Host stack: 
[23] pce_principal:send(@3221888617/prolog_debugger, icon(resource(debug)))
[22]  Send-method on @3221888617/prolog_debugger: prolog_debugger->initialise(0,main)
[21] '$c_call_prolog'
[20] pce_principal:send(new(_G397, prolog_debugger(0, main)), open)
[19] prolog_gui:send_pce(prolog_gui:send(new(_G397, prolog_debugger(0, main)), open))
```

I've tried to change the DISPLAY variable but it then prompts:

> [PCE fatal: @display/display: 
>   Failed to connect to X-server at `:0.0.': malformed address: :0.0.
>
> ---
>
> - You MUST be running the X11 Windowing environment.  If you are,   *
> - check the setting of your DISPLAY environment variable as well    *
> - the access rights to your X11 server.  See xauth(1) and xhost(1). *
>
>   ---
>
>   ```
>   in:     <No exception goal> ] Host stack:  [23] pce_principal:send(@3221888913/prolog_debugger, icon(resource(debug)))
>   ```
>
>   [22] Send-method on @3221888913/prolog_debugger:
>     prolog_debugger->initialise(0,main)  [21] '$c_call_prolog'  [20]
>     pce_principal:send(new(_G397, prolog_debugger(0, main)), open)  [19]
>     prolog_gui:send_pce(prolog_gui:send(new(_G397, prolog_debugger(0,
>     main)), open))

Comment: It is altogether quite difficult to get SWI-Prolog properly running on cygwin. Is there a reason not to use the pre-compiled Windows binaries, or even use Linux (in a virtual machine if necessary)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program you are executing requires an X11 server to render its output. The environment variable DISPLAY has to point to this X11 server. It's not enough to just define the environment variable. It has to point to an actual implementation of X11.

On Windows you can use Xming as an implementation of X11.

Comment: I installed Xming and when I launched it, the icon and the value :0.0 appears in the bottom right corner. So assume, this is the value to set the DISPLAY variable. There is no error anymore but nothing happens, it immediately returns from the trace and exits the swipl commando. However running xeyes did work.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I use SWI-Prolog on Windows. Current version Windows 10.

Recently I needed to use SWI-Prolog on Linux, Unicode issue.

Solution:

1. Install WSL with Ubuntu on Windows
2. Install SWI-Prolog via the PPA

Versions
Windows: 10.0.18362 N/A Build 18362
WSL: 1
Ubuntu: 18.04.2 LTS
SWI-Prolog: (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.1.22)

Following [Running Graphical Applications](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WSL#Running_Graphical_Applications) installed [VcXsrv Windows X Server](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/)

Started VcXsrv
Started WSL
In Ubuntu on WSL $ `export DISPLAY=:0`
Start swipl in Ubuntu on WSL
gtrace with a query
This will start a X-Windows client on Windows 10 with the GUI debugger running.